# getting decimal values from a binary file in perl

Tags: perl, binary, decimal

I have a binary file that contains my data. the data are in 42bytes blocks. I am trying to take this data block by block and print the equivalent decimal values in lines in a csv file. At the moment I am trying to first just get the decimal data on the screen.
The file when opened with txt Editor Looks Shows this kinda stuff:

```
 + Ö K¹Lÿ    ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    | D Ö ä
 + Ö K¹*ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    | D Ö ä
 + Ö K¸4ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    | D Ö ä
 + Ö Kµ*ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    | D Ö ä
# 9 Ö K©[ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    | D Ö ä
" 9 Ö K©‰ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    | D Ö ä
+ 0 Ö K¯¿ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    | D Ö ä
 9 Ö Kªµÿ    ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    | D Ö ä
 3 Ö K¨–ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    | D Ö ä
 3 Ö Kªxÿ    ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    | D Ö ä
 Z Ö K¶:ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    ÿ    | D Ö ä
...
```

if I open it with a hex Editor then I get this :

```
00 44 00 D6 00 E4 07 04 07 13 35 13 00 00 30 00 D6 00 4B C9 0D FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 7C 00 44 00 D6 00 E4 07 04 07 13 35 39 00 00 30 00 D6 00 4B C5 10 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 7C 00 44 00 D6 00 E4 07 04 07 13 36 16 00 00 33 00 D6 00 4B CE 44 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 7C 00 44 00 D6 00 E4 07 04 07 13 36 2F 00 00 30 00 D6 00 4B CE 12 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 7C 00 44 00 D6 00 E4 07 04 07 13 37 0C 00 00 33 00 D6 00 4B CE 21 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 7C 00 44 00 D6 00 E4 07 04 07 13 38 04 00 00 30 00 D6 00 4B D7 0A FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00...
```

The idea I have is to read the Input file one Byte at a time and store it in an array of size 42 and then convert the 42 bytes and print them, then continue on to the next 42 Bytes.
this is what I have so far. I am using perl btw.
use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use feature 'say';
use feature "switch";
use v5.16;

my $input_file = 'pathtofile\ZONE0.txt'; 
open my $fh, '<', $input_file or die;
binmode $input_file;
my @decimal_values=[42];
my @buffer=[42];
while ( <$fh>) {
    my $i;
    for (my $i=0; $i<42; $i++) {
        read($fh, @buffer[$i], 1);
        my @decimal_values = map (eval("0b$_"), @buffer);
    }
    say @decimal_values;
}
```

when I execute the Code, I just get this message :

```
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 18248) line 1, near "0bb" (#3)
```

i am not sure what am i doing wrong!

Comment: There are several syntax problems in your code. Your `while` loop is checking if the variable that contains the path to the file is true, so it's endless.  You should be seeing a bunch of warnings because you redeclare `$i` in a smaller scope. Your `die` uses `$_` instead of `$!` so the error message wouldn't be visible. The line where you declare `@buffer` with all those lexicals makes no sense. What are you actually trying to do? It looks like you've collected a bunch of different Perl examples from the web and combined them.

Comment: @simbabque i meant to write the equivalent of !eof in the while loop to parse the whole file. The Buffer line is needed later when  i will Need to use specific Bytes for later treatement

Comment: `map (eval("0b$_"), @buffer` what is this trying to do? Does the file contain ascii coding of binary data, like `0110010011...`? (That is: In text format, since you use prefix `0b`) On the other hand, I would guess that the file contained binary numbers such that the number 7 is encoded as a byte with value 7 and not as 8 bytes of ascii with value "00000111"

Comment: @HåkonHægland it is a binary file with 0 and 1, I am trying to convert the values in that file to decimal and print them. i am not sure that Methode works though. I added more info to the Question.

Comment: `use feature "switch"`, wow, been a while since I saw that one. It was experimental and not recommended then, wonder if its been fixed since. My guess is no, and you should not try to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example of how you can read a binary file in Perl:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use constant BUFSIZE => 42;

my $input_file = 'ZONE0.dat';
open (my $BIN, "<:raw", $input_file) or die "can't open the file $input_file: $!";
my $buffer;
while (1) {
    my $bytes_read = sysread $BIN, $buffer, BUFSIZE;
    die "Could not read file $input_file: $!" if !defined $bytes_read;
    last if $bytes_read <= 0;
    my @decimal = map { unpack "C", $_ } split //, $buffer;
    say join ", ", @decimal;
}
close $BIN;
```

Comment: so when the Content of the file is read into $buffer, $bufffer will be one string of 42 Bytes Right?

Comment: @waffles123 Yes that is correct, for each iteration of the `while` loop we read 42 bytes of the file

Comment: that is not exactly what i Need. i would like an Array of siye 42. becuase i Need the singular Bytes for later use.

Comment: @waffles123 The bytes are extracted into the array `@decimal`

Comment: ok, Thank you, one last Question. the files I have are .txt but I see you used a .dat. is that not going to cause an issue?

Comment: You are welcome. No the file extension does not have an influence on the result, but it is common that text files have extension `.txt` (and since the file is not a text file I chose another extension to indicate that)